# Select rows from a DataFrame for condition that is "close enough" to a column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have some data like this:

```
Flights                    AB   AA    AC        AD
ID   R       Length                                
5    A       0.000000    NaN   NaN   NaN  0.454545
     B       0.076660   12.0  42.0  51.0  0.272727
     C01     0.243669    NaN   NaN   NaN  0.454545
     C02     0.495551   20.0   NaN  55.0  0.727273
     C03     0.747433    NaN   NaN   NaN  0.636364
     C04     1.078713   20.0  54.0  65.0  0.727273
     C05     1.582478    NaN   NaN   NaN  0.909091
     C06     2.245038   20.0  50.0  61.0  1.181818
```

This is a MultiIndex dataframe, where the indicies are `[ID, R, Length]`.

I would like to select rows based on the `Length` index. But I would like to select rows based on some fairly specific criteria.

**Q:** I want to select rows, based on index `Length`, which are approximately a multiple of 0.25 in the `Length` index *as well as the first row*. So what does that mean?

Qualifying rows in the `Length` index are not quite multiples of 0.25, but *almost*. So I would like a function that basically returns this, where I also want the first row which always has a value of `0.0` in the `Length` index:

```
Flights                    AB   AA    AC        AD
ID   R       Length                                
5    A       0.000000    NaN   NaN   NaN  0.454545
     C01     0.243669    NaN   NaN   NaN  0.454545
     C02     0.495551   20.0   NaN  55.0  0.727273
     C03     0.747433    NaN   NaN   NaN  0.636364
     C04     1.078713   20.0  54.0  65.0  0.727273
     C05     1.582478    NaN   NaN   NaN  0.909091
     C06     2.245038   20.0  50.0  61.0  1.181818
```

or if I am interested in multiples of 0.5:

```
Flights                    AB   AA    AC        AD
ID   R       Length                                
5    A       0.000000    NaN   NaN   NaN  0.454545
     C02     0.495551   20.0   NaN  55.0  0.727273
     C04     1.078713   20.0  54.0  65.0  0.727273
     C05     1.582478    NaN   NaN   NaN  0.909091
```

in this case the numbers in the `Length` column are *almost* multiples 0.5 but not quite. So how can I create a filter rule like this?

Comment: Not sure but somewhere you have to implement around using https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-485-a-function-for-testing-approximate-equality math.close() or similar function. Cannot test but should be a good point to start with.